# Installed VS code, there is no builder to build my code, even though I installed MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I have very recently installed VS code and am an absolute newbie. I first had a different problem because I installed the wrong type of MinGW-W64, which I have now uninstalled, then it seemed to fix the problem, until I tried to build the code. A photo of what going to terminal > run build task shows me is shown in this photo.
[Terminal>Run Build Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsuRE.png)

Extra details: I am using 3 c++ addons, C/C++ version 1.4.0, C/C++ Extension Pack version 1.0.0 and C++ Intellisense version 0.2.2. My code is an extremely simple and correct:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

My goal: I'm hoping to be able to run this code as intended in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp (the tutorial I followed)

To show clarification on error messages, see this photo: [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwANs.png)

Comment: are you able to call the compiler from the command line to compile this code?

Comment: How do I call the compiler?

Comment: @Pransterbunny can you type ```g++ --version``` in the command line and see the response?

Comment: Aak yes, I do see a response.  x_is_not_a_number, I tried using g++ helloworld.cpp and then ./a.out and It provides me with the error message firstly, 
g++.exe: error: helloworld.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
Then the next error message is
./a.out : The term './a.out' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,   
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the  
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./a.out
+ ~~~~~~~
plus 3 extra lines, this comment is too long.

Comment: Make sure you are running the command in the same directory where your ```helloworld.cpp``` file is present

Comment: I 100% am, I have added a photo to the original post for clarification @Aak

Comment: Your directory is wrong. Your file is in the ...\Desktop folder but you are running command in other directory. Change the directory to ...\Desktop

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry about that, how do I change the directory to \Desktop from whatever it is right now?

Comment: I posted an answer, have a look at it.

Comment: [Get Started with C++ and Mingw-w64 in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) is a handy link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the error message, you are currently executing the program in `C:\Users\{username}` directory however your source code file `helloworld.cpp` is present in `C:\Users\{username}\OneDrive\Desktop` folder.

use `cd "C:\Users\{username}\OneDrive\Desktop"` in your terminal to navigate to the folder and then run the `g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld` command. After that run `.\helloworld` to run your program.

Note that if you using VS code to build your program as mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_build-hello-world), then you only have to execute the `.\helloworld` command to run it.

Comment: I have switched my name out with the example John Smith. My error message shows: Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Smith\OneDrive\Desktop'.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd C:\Users\John Smith\OneDrive\Desktop
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Comment: Please use the username which you are having in your computer.

Comment: I have followed your instructions well and all has worked, the output is "Hello World", will I have to always use the terminal from now on when running and compiling code?

Comment: I have not used VS Code to build and run C++ programs, you can explore if it provides capability to run the program after building it as well. in any case, you can always rely on the terminal to build and run your program

Comment: I looked around and found this YouTube video- https://youtu.be/jvg4VtYEhKU .
You can take a look at it to run the program directly without using terminal